# Delphi tree view with checkboxes: sometimes the checkboxes are invisible

Tags: windows, delphi, checkbox, treeview

I have a problem. I have a TTreeview descendant that shows checkboxes just fine on my own computer and all other I have tested myself.

`TVS_CHECKBOXES` is set using `SetWindowLong`. In the `Loaded` method I set/maintain checked states with `StateIndex := 2;`, `Item.State := TVIS_CHECKED`, etc.

So far so good. But now a person contacted me where the treeview checkboxes does not show *at all* on his WindowsXP SP3. (He even provided me with a screenshot.) From the program behavior, I can say the default-checked-nodes are working since program otherwise from customer description behaves like expected.

I have not been able to find similar symptoms described anywhere. All computers I have tested on, it works well. But the screenshot from the customer shows that there's a problem :(

My best guess is that it's some `RecreateWnd` that on some systems reset the treeview checkbox mode?

My options for testing is limited since I can not reproduce problem on my own computers, so would like to know if others have other suggestions I can try before I send new beta code to the person who's system seems to be hiding the treeview checkboxes?

Comment: Put the SetWindowLong call in an overriden `CreateWnd` and then you'll know if RecreateWnd is the problem.

Comment: I am doing that right now! Only thing is that I have send each attempt/change to the user since I can't test it myself. I will write again when I know if the change works or not. (May be a day or two depending when the person responds.)

Comment: This sounds just like a GroupWise bug that only exhibits on my machine at the office.

Comment: The situation is this. Before the tester got a chance to to try the new beta, he reported the problem had solved itself by installing/reinstalling the application... I did ask the tester to install fixed-beta and report back if problem ever occured again. So far he has not contacted me about it. I guess I will keep this question open just in case someone can contribute with a verified explanation and solution to the cause of the original problem.

Answer (score 4):

Setting this style in an overriden `CreateWnd` could be too late according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If you want to use this style, you must set the TVS_CHECKBOXES style with SetWindowLong **after** you create the treeview control, and **before** you populate the tree. Otherwise, the checkboxes might appear unchecked, depending on timing issues.

Now, this seems like a small egg-and-chicken dilemma, because the VCL does not provide a real solution for this exact moment in time. Setting this style before the inherited CreateWnd call is not possible because there is no handle yet. But after the inherited call, the tree might already be populated due to recreation. (The VCL streams the nodes back in `TCustomTreeView.CreateWnd`).

But since this just looks like a simple style modification, you could (also) try override [`CreateParams`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Controls.TWinControl.CreateParams) and add this flag to `Params.Style` which works just as fine here.

```
procedure TMyTreeView.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  Params.Style := Params.Style or TVS_CHECKBOXES;
end;
```

Though I cannot reproduce the problem either. And nodes appearing unchecked does not match being unvisible at all, so I really wonder this would fix it.

Comment: You've quoted the documentation, fine, but then failed to follow it. It has to be after the window has been created. You set the flag before it's created. The right approach is to call SetWindowLong in an overridden CreateWnd.

Comment: @David Thanks, I clarified my answer. Also thanks for your [subtle bump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582903).

Comment: Just a quick note: Like I wrote in initial questions, I was already using SetWindowLong etc.