# Programmatically check a custom treeview checkbox

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to programatically check a custom checkbox in a treeview. What I mean by custom, is that I call the below code to enable these checkboxes:

```
SetWindowLong(TreeView1.Handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(TreeView1.Handle, GWL_STYLE) or TVS_CHECKBOXES)
```

I tried the below code to check it, but it did not work.

```
  Node := TreeView1.Selected;
  TVItem.mask := TVIF_STATE;
  TVItem.hItem := Node.ItemId;
  TreeView_GetItem(Node.TreeView.Handle, TVItem);
  TVItem.stateMask := TVIS_CHECKED;
  TVItem.mask := TVIS_CHECKED;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is TreeView_SetItem?

Comment: BTW, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7178017/243614) answer before you go further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your state mask wrong, there's no `TVIS_CHECKED` state mask (in fact there is no `TVIS_CHECKED`, more on that later). Check boxes are managed through an image list, this is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tree-view-control-window-styles#TVS_CHECKBOXES).

Additionally, of course, you have to call `TreeView_SetItem`:

```delphi
const
  TVIS_CHECKED = 2 shl 12;
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
  TVItem: TTVItem;
begin
  Node := TreeView1.Selected;
  if Assigned(Node) then begin
    TVItem.mask := TVIF_STATE;
    TVItem.hItem := Node.ItemId;
    TreeView_GetItem(Node.TreeView.Handle, TVItem);

    TVItem.stateMask := TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
    TVItem.state := TVIS_CHECKED;
    TreeView_SetItem(Node.TreeView.Handle, TVItem);
  end;
end;
```

---

Normally I'd advise to call `TreeView_SetCheckState` but the VCL has got a weird error in the translation of the macro.

This is the macro in the header:

```c
#define TreeView_SetCheckState(hwndTV, hti, fCheck) \
  TreeView_SetItemState(hwndTV, hti, INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK((fCheck)?2:1), TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK)
```

where

```c
#define INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(i) ((i) << 12)
```

This is why the made-up `TVIS_CHECKED` is $2000, the define shifts 2 12 bits left when `fCheck` is true (2 is the index of the checked image, 1 is unchecked).

This is VCL's translation:

```delphi
function TreeView_SetCheckState(hwndTV: HWND; hti: HTreeItem; fCheck: BOOL): UINT;
var
  LState: UINT;
begin
  if IndexToStateImageMask(Integer(fCheck)) = 0 then
    LState := 1
  else
    LState := 2;
  Result := TreeView_SetItemState(hwndTV, hti, LState, TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK);
```

where `IndexToStateImageMask` is

```delphi
Result := I shl 12;
```

Strangely, the VCL shifts `fCheck` 12 bits and then calls `TreeView_SetItemState` with a state that makes no sense for a state image mask (`TVIS_FOCUSED` (1), `TVIS_SELECTED` (2)).

This is XE2, I suggest to test the macro first if you are working with a later version.

Comment: Sertac Akyuz, thank you so much for your help, it worked as intended. Also I learned more about VCL. Usually I don't go too deep into the Windows docs. Thanks again

Comment: In the same fashion, do you know how can I get an event for each time this is fired? Example: When then user clicks on a checkbox it fires the "OnChecking" event?

Comment: You're welcome. Regular onclick seem to be fine for a mouse click. However when you switch the state of an item with the keyboard, AFAICT the only notifications that fire  are the onget[selected|image]index. And of course key down. Probably the implementation would cover keydowns and clicks, might lead to some spaghetti code. Would be a valid question I guess.

Comment: Thank you again Sertac, I'll try something with Click and Key Up/Down!

Answer (score 1):

What do you have TVIS_CHECKED defined as? It should be:

```
const
  TVIS_CHECKED = $2000;
```

Then, assuming Value is a Boolean of whether or not the item is checked:

```
FillChar(TVItem, SizeOf(TVItem), 0);
TVItem.hItem := Node.ItemId;
TVItem.mask := TVIF_STATE;
TVItem.stateMask := TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
if Value then
  TVItem.state := TVIS_CHECKED
else
  TVItem.state := TVIS_CHECKED shr 1;
TreeView_SetItem(Node.Handle, TVItem);
```

Comment: Indeed it was the SetItem I was missing