# How to create Delphi component inherited from few other components?

Tags: delphi, components

Tutorials that I found about how to create delphi components were nice, but they only used one of existing components as object to inherit actions from. Something like this

```
unit CountBtn;

interface

uses
 Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
 StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
 TCountBtn = class(TButton)
  private
  FCount: integer;
  protected
  procedure Click;override;
  public
  procedure ShowCount;
  published
  property Count:integer read FCount write FCount;
  constructor Create(aowner:Tcomponent); override;
 end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
 RegisterComponents('Mihan Components', [TCountBtn]);
end;

constructor TCountBtn.Create(aowner:Tcomponent);
begin
 inherited create(Aowner);
end;

procedure Tcountbtn.Click;
begin
 inherited click;
 FCount:=FCount+1;
end;

procedure TCountBtn.ShowCount;
begin
 Showmessage('On button '+ caption+' you clicked: '+inttostr(FCount)+' times');
end;

end.
```

But what should I do if I need component which use few elements? Lets say, I got `Button` and `Edit` field. And on button click there in edit field should appers text the same as on button. I start to make it like this, but seems like it's not gonna work as I want:

```
unit TestComp;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TUiCompU = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FButton: TButton;
    FEdit: TEdit;

  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure Paint; override;
    //wrong!
    procedure FButton.Click;override
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
    //wrong!
     property ButtonText: String read FButton.Caption write FButton.Caption;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Ui', [TUiCompU]);
end;

{ TUiCompU }

constructor TUiCompU.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Width := 200;
  Height := 50;

  FButton := TButton.Create(Self);
  FButton.SetSubComponent(True);
  FButton.Parent := Self;
  FButton.Top := 8;
  FButton.Left := 50;
  FButton.Width := 35;
  FButton.Name := 'Button';

  FEdit := TEdit.Create(Self);
  FEdit.SetSubComponent(True);
  FEdit.Parent := Self;
  FEdit.Top := 8;
  FEdit.Left := 84;
  FEdit.Width := 121;
  FEdit.Name := 'Edit';
end;

procedure TUiCompU.Paint;
begin
  Canvas.Rectangle(ClientRect);
end;

end.
```

How should I add here `Click` procedure, which is realte to click on the button? And is there are good tutorial about how to made good components using others? (I need to create something like slideshow component btw).
Thank you, and sorry for my english.

Comment: try Customs Containers and Components Pack. It was created by Borland Moscow office for Delphi 4/5 as a way to turn the form (with all the components placed there, events, properties et all) into a brand new composite component. It was cool and i think the very approach (based on encapsulation) was better than `TFrame` that Delphi 5 introduced (and that have no encapsulation). I heard on SourceForge there is a port of CCCP to Delphi XE2 but i did not personally tried it. And old how-to with the pictures stripped: http://www.howtodothings.com/computers/a1167-custom-containers-pack-ccpack-5.html

Comment: Some advanced stuff related to this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582903/whats-the-difference-between-createwnd-and-createwindowhandle

Comment: @user928177263 nice to see that the question is useful and ppl checking it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write methods for the subcomponent events, but it has one big weakness; if you publish those subcomponents, there is a risk that someone will steal you this binding by writing own method:

```
type
  TUiCompU = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FEdit: TEdit;
    FButton: TButton;
    procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure EditKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TUiCompU.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

  FButton := TButton.Create(Self);
  ...
  FButton.OnClick := ButtonClick;

  FEdit := TEdit.Create(Self);
  ...
  FEdit.OnKeyDown := EditKeyDown;
end;

procedure TUiCompU.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // do whatever you want here
end;

procedure TUiCompU.EditKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  // do whatever you want here
end;
```

Comment: oh thanks for the answer! i even saw one of your answers almost few minutes ago! but is there way to avoid such bindings?

Comment: Well, that binding is the simplest way to achieve what you're going to implement and except the risk of stealing the event handler (if you make those subcontrols public), there is nothing wrong on it. As far as I know, any other ways would require to crack those subcontrols e.g. by overriding their window procedures or introducing some sort of notification mechanism from their dynamic methods (methods like `Click`, `KeyDown` etc.).