# How to create a derived component of TMS TAdvPage in Delphi

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-xe2

I am programming software using the TMS component library. Specifically to this question I am using the component tAdvToolBarPager.

This allows me to create different tAdvPage. (like a toolbar) Think of MsOffice where you have pages like; File, Home, Page Layout, Data, Etc...

I find myself wanting to reuse the pages I created in other applications.

For instance, my Page "Data" has all the controls required to process a serial data either from an RS 232 port or via the Network.

My "Data" Page:

[image: Img]

Presently, I copy and paste the page and all related code from one application to the other.

I am sure I do not need to explain how this in impractical.

For lack of a better word, or maybe it is the right word, I would like to create a derived component that I could drag and drop in my applications from the IDE tool palette. This "component" would have all the controls + code in order to be self sufficient. (like a small application) Also, if I change the "component" code, it would apply to ALL my software using this component. Of course I need to easily be able to access all the controls in the "component"; text boxes, combo boxes etc.

I had a quick look at creating a component and found it looked very complex since there is no visual element. (Some of my pages are more complex than the example I provided)

Is there an easy way to copy and paste the visual components of my page + code to a "component". If not, how do I go about it?

I've use the framing method before where I docked a border less form to a panel but I am wondering if there is a "cleaner" way to do this.

If someone could give me an example, I would likely be able to figure it out. Alas, what I have found on internet has confused me a bit and I am not too sure what is the best approach anymore.

Ex: Draw a TButton + Tedit in a Tpanel. button pressed = "hello world" in edit box. Create "component" from Tpanel. (I can take likely take it from there)

I am intermediate self thought and am not a full time programmer this may be a silly question but I don't want to go down the wrong path and realize I need to start everything all over again...

Thanks,
E.

Comment: Turns out I found the answer on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723605/how-to-create-delphi-component-inherited-from-few-other-components

Answer (score 0):

```
type
   TMyPager = class( TAdvToolBarPager)
   private
      ....
   protected
      procedure Click;override;
   public
      procedure MyNewProcedure;
   published
      property 
       .....
       .....
      constructor Create(aowner:Tcomponent); override;
end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
   RegisterComponents('My Component', [TMyPager]);
end;

constructor TMyPager.Create(aowner:Tcomponent);
begin
   inherited create(Aowner);
end;

procedure TMyPager.Click;
begin
   inherited click;
    .....
    .....
end;

procedure TMyPager.MyNewProcedure;
begin
   ......
   ......
end;

end.
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort but it did not offer enough details to answer my question. Found a link which helped me figure it out. Cheers