# How do I make form or windowed control RecreateWnd-aware properly?

Tags: delphi, vcl

As you know, window handles of windowed controls (this includes forms) are considered volatile. That is, setting some properties may cause control to destroy its window handle and then recreate (there is a bunch of examples of that technique, search `StdCtrls` for `RecreateWnd`).

So, when I need to register my HWND with OS after creation and unregister it before destruction I should override corresponding method pair. Brief look to `Controls` and `Forms` gave me 3 pairs, all of them virtual:

- CreateHandle/DestroyHandle
- CreateWindowHandle/DestroyWindowHandle
- CreateWnd/DestroyWnd

Are there any more pairs? Which pair should I override for a form? And Which pair for general windowed control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override `CreateWnd()` and `DestroyWnd()` in most situations.  Override `DestroyWnd()` to do window unregistrations, temporarily save any window-dependent data if the `csRecreating` flag is present in the `ControlState` property, and call the inherited `DestroyWnd()` (which calls `DestroyWindowHandle()`) to destroy the HWND.  Override `CreateWnd()` to call the inherited `CreateWnd()` (which calls `CreateWindowHandle()`) to create the HWND, load and discard temporary window-dependent data if any was previously saved, and do window registrations.

Override `CreateWindowHandle()` and `DestroyWindowHandle()` when you need to obtain/free an HWND through other means than normal Win32 `CreateWindow/Ex()` and `DestroyWindow()` calls.  For example, `TForm` overrides these to create/free MDI child windows by sending `WM_MDICREATE` and `WM_MDIDESTROY` messages to its `ClientHandle` window.

I have never seen `CreateHandle()` and `DestroyHandle()` overridden for anything useful.

See this discussion for more details:

[What's the difference between CreateWnd and CreateWindowHandle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582903/whats-the-difference-between-createwnd-and-createwindowhandle)